# C++ Eigen read-only sparse block subexpression? How to write?

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to create one large matrix from four different matrices using Eigen's block expressions.

However, adding the first matrix in the top left corner results in the error:

```
error: static assertion failed: THIS_SPARSE_BLOCK_SUBEXPRESSION_IS_READ_ONLY
  451 |       EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(T)==0, THIS_SPARSE_BLOCK_SUBEXPRESSION_IS_READ_ONLY);
```

I was not able to find exactly what causes this issue. It's really important that I do not convert my matrix to a dense representation. Here's my code:

```
 Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> top_left = K + Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>(K.transpose());

 Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> block_laplacian_sq;
 block_laplacian_sq.resize(top_left.rows() + C.rows(), top_left.cols() + C.rows());
 block_laplacian_sq.topLeftCorner(top_left.rows(), top_left.cols()) = top_left; 
//                                                       error here^^^
```

Comment: To vertically stack sparse matrices check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41777589/6870253 (this could relatively simple be extended to stack multiple matrices). Also see this feature request: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1420

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the tutorial explains](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html):

> Regarding read-access, sparse matrices expose the same API than for dense matrices to access to sub-matrices such as blocks, columns, and rows. See Block operations for a detailed introduction. However, for performance reasons, writing to a sub-sparse-matrix is much more limited, and currently only contiguous sets of columns (resp. rows) of a column-major (resp. row-major) `SparseMatrix` are writable. Moreover, this information has to be known at compile-time, leaving out methods such as `block(...)` and `corner*(...)`.

For your particular use case where you want to initialize the top-left corner, you can use the fact that after resizing, uninitialized matrix entries are implicitly zero. So this works:

```cpp
top_left.conservativeResize(block_laplacian_sq.rows(), top_left.cols());
block_laplacian_sq.leftCols(top_left.cols()) = top_left;
```

But that doesn't help you when you want to initialize the bottom rows. Assuming you want to initialize all 4 corners with sub-matrices, I would recommend building one large vector of triplets (see [Convert an Eigen matrix to Triplet form C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685877/convert-an-eigen-matrix-to-triplet-form-c)) and then initialize the final matrix all in one go.

A potential alternative is to fill a row-major matrix with the entries for the full column-wise sub-matrix. I can't see how this would be faster but maybe it is more elegant for your use case.

```cpp
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> left(
      block_laplacian_sq.rows(), top_left.cols());
left.topRows(top_left.rows()) = top_left;
left.bottomRows(bottom_left.rows()) = bottom_left;
block_laplacian_sq.leftCols(left.cols()) = left;
```

(obviously you would try to rearrange expressions to avoid row-major <-> column-major changes where possible)